# mod_rewrite and relative urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm setting up some simple url rewriting rules using mod_rewrite and a .htacces file, but I've got some problems.
If I set up the .htacces this way:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule /index.html /index.php [L]
```

when I call from the browser this url:
http://localhost/~dave/mySite/index.html
I got a 404 error.

Using this .htacces instead

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule /index.html http://localhost/~dave/mySite/index.php [L]
```

everything works fine and I get the index.php page I'm expecting.
Am I forced to user absolute urls as the target of a rewrite? Is this a Apache configuration problem?

I'm using Max OS X 10.6.2 with its standard Apache installation.

Comment: Where do you want to use that .htaccess file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The RewriteBase base directive is setting a base path; you don't need to provide absolute paths in the redirection rules.
2. The rule pattern is not plain text; it's a regular expression.
3. If you set a full URL as target you instruct the browser to redirect to that other location; that kind of redirection is not transparent to the user.

To sum up, try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.html $1/index.php [L]
```

That should sort it.